# Multiple Instances of Excel one Instance Freezes VBA in Another

Tags: excel, windows-8.1, instances, vba

While working with multiple instances of Excel, if a VBA procedure is running with one instance of Excel VBA seems to be hung in all other instances of Excel.

I assume this is because there is only a single instance of VBA running?

Is there anyway to run multiple instances if VBA or otherwise work round this problem (within an Excel / VBA), or can someone point me to an article explaining how works please.

I am using Excel 2010 & Windows 8.

Comment: Hmm... run the two instances on two computers?

Comment: This is definitely not the case in my installation of 2007.  I work with a spreadsheet that uses VBA to parse large csv files - 20 minutes per parse.  I have run it in four concurrent instances on my quadcore and it takes about 30 minutes.  (Instead of the 80 that running consecutively would)

Comment: you need to open each `book` in separated excel instance; there are many ways for this;[link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/40a2eb2f-bb54-42c8-babf-e243240df282/opening-files-in-multiple-instances-of-excel-2010); but for me;open the first `book` normally (double click); for the other book, press `WIN` + `R` to show the `Run` dialog; then type: `EXCEL /?`  this will open a new instance of Excel;then `file`menu -> `open` the second `book`.

Comment: Adam, thats similar to my scenario, but I am solving something numerically, and it takes about 10-20mins.  The problem is that, while I have two separate excel process running when I try and do anything in VBA in the second instance of Excel while the first is still calculating excel hangs waiting for the VBA in the first instance to run.  I can do things in spreadsheets in the different instances of excel fine, but as soon as I go to VBA i hit problems.  This occurs even if I try it in anther version of excel e.g. 2010 and 2003.